# What is the difference between .NET Core runtime and ASP.NET Core runtime?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-runtime

If I'm not wrong, ASP.NET Core projects are .NET Core console applications that set up HTTP Server. It has a `Program` class with `Main` method. All specified ASP.NET Core namespaces and types are distributed via NuGet packages (referenced in `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK).

My logic says me "for running ASP.NET Core apps you only .NET Core runtime", but...

- In [dotnet download runtime website](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0), there are downloads for .NET Core runtime and for for ASP.NET Core runtime.
- In DockerHub, there are a image for [.NET runtime](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-runtime/) and a image for [ASP.NET Core runtime](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet/).
- When I run `dotnet --list-runtimes`, I see:

  - Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.5
  - Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.5

What are the difference between the both runtimes? Can I run ASP.NET application with .NET Core runtime and without ASP.NET Core runtime? In negative case, why specified runtime for ASP.NET Core is needed? I don't need specified runtime for running e.g. Monogame projects.

Comment: This question is closed as duplicate, but it is not duplicate. The linked question ask about difference between .NET Core and ASP.NET Core (referring to the framework, not the runtime). I'm asking about the ASP.NET Core runtime (the specific runtime, not the framework) and why it is needed instead of the .NET Core runtime.

Comment: This question should NEVER have been put as a "duplicate". 
I am also interested in the differences, did you find any answers on your own?

Comment: Hi @MrDave1999, see this GitHub discussion for more information https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/discussions/59902